# PHP: How to tell if PDF has embedded fonts?

Tags: pdf, command-line, ghostscript, postscript, pdftk

Given a PDF document, is there a way to tell if it has embedded fonts? I'm working on the problem posted here: [PDF: How to Optimize Filesize & Convert to PNG (embedded fonts problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774995/pdf-how-to-optimize-filesize-convert-to-png-embedded-fonts-problem). Perhaps I can rework some of my application's logic based on whether a PDF has embedded fonts or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pdffonts` (*nix) or `pdffonts.exe` (*doz). They are part of [*XPDF*](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html).

1. To see which fonts are used (not necessarily embedded!) on pages 4-6 of a PDF:

   ```
   pdffonts ^
       -f 4 ^
       -l 6 ^
       input.pdf
   ```
2. To get a list of all fonts used in a PDF, simply skip the `-f 4 -l 6` part...
3. Now to differentiate between *embedded* and *non-embedded fonts*, learn...

   (a) ...the general meaning of the `yes` and `no` keywords, and
   (b) ...how to interprete these keywords in the context of a list column carrying the heading `emb`